# How to solve the problem of not receiving notifications in flutter fcm

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm having an issue where notifications are visible in the simulator but not on the actual phone.

**main.dart**

```
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:web_view/screen/home_screen.dart';

@pragma('vm:entry-point')
Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  print('Handling a background message ${message.messageId}');
}

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);

  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  final fcmToken = await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getToken();
  print(fcmToken);

  FirebaseMessaging messaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;

  NotificationSettings settings = await messaging.requestPermission(
    alert: true,
    announcement: false,
    badge: true,
    carPlay: false,
    criticalAlert: false,
    provisional: false,
    sound: true,
  );

  FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
    print('Got a message whilst in the foreground!');
    print('Message data: ${message.data}');

    if (message.notification != null) {
      print('Message also contained a notification: ${message.notification}');
    }
  });

  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: HomeScreen(),
    ),
  );
}
```

As a result of sending a push notification from fcm to the device, the fcm console showed that 2 requests were sent (phone, simulator). However, no notification was actually sent to my phone.

Both the simulator and the phone are Android.